GitHub Workflow SSL Certificates
I have a React app, built with Vite, that makes use of the server section in the Vite config to allow local HTTPS:
vite.config.ts:
...
  server: {
    host: true, // to support Docker
    https: {
      cert: './localhost+1.pem',
      key: './localhost+1-key.pem',
    },
...

Now I want to configure a GitHub Workflow to run the vitest tests in PR checks… this checks out, lints and builds correctly, but when it gets to the test step, I get an error:
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Error ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
    at node:internal/tls/secure-context:70:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setCerts (node:internal/tls/secure-context:68:3)
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:186:5)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:116:3)
    at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1486:27)
    at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1350:8)
    at new Server (node:https:75:3)
    at createServer (node:https:133:10)
    at createWebSocketServer (file:///home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:61088:28) {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
}

This seems to be because it can't find the configured cert & key.
I've base64 encoded both, stored these encoded versions as secrets on the repo, and added the following to my workflow YAML file (as suggested in this GitHub discussion:
...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install the app
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build the app
        run: npm run build --if-present

      - name: Lint the code
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Write Key File
        env:
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSL_KEY }}
        run: |
          echo "$KEY" | base64 --decode > ${HOME}/localhost+1-key.pem

      - name: Write Certificate File
        env:
          CERT: ${{ secrets.SSL_CERT }}
        run: |
          echo "$CERT" | base64 --decode > ${HOME}/localhost+1.pem

      - name: Test the app
        run: npm test

      - name: Tidy up
        run: rm ${HOME}/localhost+1.pem ${HOME}/localhost_1-key.pem

The output of the Write Certificate File step is:
echo "$CERT" | base64 --decode > ${HOME}/localhost+1.pem
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    CERT: ***

(Of course, GitHub hides the actual cert in the logs.)
but I'm still getting the exact same error.
I'm at a loss now as to why the pem files still can't be found... I can't tell if it's not creating them, or not finding them once they are properly created.
